# Stoke law determend the viscosity of liquid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, viscosity

In an experiment to determine the viscosity by the Stoke method.  When we throw the ball into the liquid it will reach a certain mark and start recording the time.  This mark what determines its location, such that it is 5 cm further from the top edge, why not more or less. And the bottom mark. What determined their location and why

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I think the question is pretty clear, actually.

Answer (score 1):

When terminal velocity has been reached then Stokes Law tells us that:

$$(\rho_p-\rho_f)g\frac43 \pi R^3=6\pi R\mu v$$

Knowing mass $m$ and velocity $v$ (and radius $R$) then allows calculating viscosity $\mu$.

But prior to reaching [terminal velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_law#Terminal_velocity_of_sphere_falling_in_a_fluid) the ball's equation of motion is:

$$(\rho_p-\rho_f)g\frac43 \pi R^3\ddot{y}-6\pi R\mu \dot{y}=0$$

where $y$ is the vertical direction.

Solving that equation allows to determine the amount of displacement $y$ that's needed before the ball's velocity has become constant (i.e. terminal).

Those who designed the experiment for you determined that distance was about $5\mathrm{cm}$.